# hammer.js dragging not start 'till finger stop on ipad screen

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

Dragging with hammer.js works on browser on pc. It fires continuously but when it comes to iPad, there is little problem. **It fires after dragging/swiping finger stops on screen**

**template**

```
<v-sheet v-pan="onPan">
    <div class="vista__img" ref="image" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + vista.image + ')' }"></div>
</v-sheet>
```

**directives**

```
 directives:{
    pan: {
      bind: function(el, binding) {
        if (typeof binding.value === "function") {
          const mc = new Hammer(el);
          mc.get("pan").set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
          mc.on("pan", binding.value);
        }
      }
    },
```

**methods && computed**

```
 methods:{
   onPan(e) {
      
      const dragOffset = -100 / this.itemWidth * e.deltaX / this.overflowRatio;
      const transform = this.currentOffset + dragOffset;
    
      this.$refs.image.style.setProperty("--x", transform);
    
      if (e.isFinal) {
        this.currentOffset = transform;
        const maxScroll = 100 - this.overflowRatio * 100;
        let finalOffset = this.currentOffset;     
      }
    },
  }

  computed: {
    overflowRatio() {
            return this.$refs.image.scrollWidth / this.$refs.image.offsetWidth;
        },
        itemWidth() {
            return this.$refs.image.scrollWidth;
    },
  },
```

Any idea about handling drag continuously on iPad?

**AND** this problem only occurs on **iPad** browsers(safari, chrome), there is no problem on iPhone

Comment: what does this "It fires finger drag is stop" mean

Comment: For example when I start to swipe/drag an image, and it doesn't fire 'till, dragging/swiping finger stop on screen. I am not sure how to explain it much more simpler...  @canbax

Comment: If you are observing this on a real physical iPad device, then reproducing is hard. If it can be reproduced on the developer tools on the browser, it could be easier to debug. Also, a minimal reproducible sample might help.

Comment: Only ipad? Or any touch device?

Comment: no problem on Iphone/safari and macbook/chrome/safari too.. the problem occurs only IPAD @MoshFeu

Comment: To reproduce this problem, one needs to run a minimal reproducible sample on a real iPad device. I don't know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can be related to a phenomenon called ***event propagation***. iOS handles it a little bit differently than other systems (yes, it's system-specific, not browser-specific and *Peter-Paul Koch* wrote an [article](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2014/02/mouse_event_bub.html) about it).

If you want to get a little bit of background, *javascript.info* has a great, extensive article about [bubbling and capturing](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).

And if you just want to solve the problem, here's an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/237) that should help. Also, [hammer.js documentation](https://hammerjs.github.io/tips/) mentions it as well.